# Ububtu upgrade stuck at the time of Unpacking fonts-sil-padauk

Tags: 14.04, boot

During the installation of the upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 the installation is stuck at "Unpacking fonts-sil-padauk (2.80-2) ...".

What should I do now?

Comment: Try booting your system in single user mode by appending `single` instead of `quiet splash` in your kernel parameter line (you will find it after the linux kernel filename in GRUB2), after booting issue this: `dpkg --force-overwrite --configure -a`. And paste the results here.

Comment: @erkin-alp-güney I would have problems trying to follow your explanation and this is a total newbie (reputation 1) with a non-working system.  :/  He probably has to print off your instructions on another computer and then carry them out on his own afterwards. ;-) Try to make your answer a bit more fool-proof...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Boot up your computer, a GRUB 2 boot menu should come, like this:
[image: GRUB 2 boot menu]
This is localised in my computer, screenshot taken via QEMU-ing into actual system.
Hit <kbd>e</kbd> here. It should be something like this:

[image: GRUB 2 edit menu] Replace the slightly underlined part by:
`single` if your `init` is `Upstart`, or `systemd.unit=emergency.target` if your `init` is `systemd`(You can learn what your default init is by issuing file `/sbin/init`, it is `/lib/upstart/upstart` if you use upstart, `/lib/systemd/systemd` or `/lib/systemd/uselessd` if you use systemd). Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> after you finish editing.

If you can bring up the emergency terminal using these and using `systemd` as `init`: something like this should come up:

[image: systemd emergency console]
Hit <kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> here, if asked, provide the `root` password.
Unfortunately I cannot take a Upstart screenshot now.
Type in `dpkg --force-overwrite --configure -a` after getting `root@hostname#` prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Erkin's answer doesn't really help in the more specialized case of going from 12 to 14 on an ARM stick computer (CX-919) in my case.  The distribution is a special case, and there is no GRUB.

I too was stuck at "Unpacking fonts-sil-padauk (2.80-2)" for hours.  This was via the popup window that informed me 14.04 was available as opposed to via a do-release-upgrade on the commandline.  Sigh, ubuntu and its bloatware font libraries.

SSHing into the stick, I see from "top":

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 277 syslog    20   0   32264   3892    892 S 123.6  0.2 181:43.21 rsyslogd    
5169 root      20   0  104620  62876  36620 R  99.7  3.0 199:01.31 trusty
```

The update is giving my cores a good workout.

Looking at dmesg:

```
[48920.554276] __find_get_block_slow() failed. block=22654, b_blocknr=3726175160
[48920.554295] b_state=0x00000029, b_size=4096
[48920.554306] device blocksize: 4096
[48920.554319] __find_get_block_slow() failed. block=22654, b_blocknr=3726175160
[48920.554337] b_state=0x00000029, b_size=4096
[48920.554348] device blocksize: 4096
```

So, this seems to possibly be hardware related.  When I check available disk space, it is completely full now, but I cannot be certain if that is due to the errors or if I didn't have enough space for the upgrade (1.9 GB was free ahead of time).  Still, it is peculiar that my upgrade died at the same install point.

My advice, check you available disk space and dmesg for clues.